# EmailConfirmation with FosUserBundle Does not work

Tags: fosuserbundle, email-confirmation, symfony-3.4

hello i have been trying to send an email Confirmation since 2 days without success with FOSUSERBUNDLE on symfony 3.4. I know this is a process FosUser makes automatically But i can't make it's work.

this is in my framework.yaml

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: App\Entity\User
registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
from_email:
       address: correo@algo.com
       sender_name: toFront
service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
```

and this is in my .env file

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://s6.g3tm.com?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=MYADDRESS&password=*****
```

i know siwftmailer is working because i can send emails to my account since the sistem.

and when i register a new user, fosuser generate a token and redirect me to /register/check-email but there is nothing in the email of such user

**EDIT**

this is my swiftmailer conf:

```
swiftmailer:
transport: smtp
host: localhost
username: correo@algo.com
password: password
port: 585
spool: { type: memory }
```

what am I wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
    swiftmailer:
transport: smtp
host: localhost
username: correo@algo.com
password: password
port: 585
spool: { type: memory }
```

the port is 587 instead of 585

following your

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://s6.g3tm.com?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=MYADDRESS&password=****
```

Your host as to be **s6.g3tm.com** not localhost

I don't use symfony 3.4, and I don't know what is the .env file you are using

With your settings, a good configuration could be:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    host: s6.g3tm.com
    username: correo@algo.com
    password: password
    port: 587
    spool: { type: memory }
```

SMTP ports are :

- 25 (normal, insecure)
- 465 (SSL)
- 587 (TLS)